# How to write a css selector in automation testwith ::before to find a element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, automated-tests

How to create a css selctor for a checkbox with  :: before selector. I want to create css selector of a radio button . 
I am using the  selector  for eg: `[data-model-cid="c279"]>label` in firepath and it shows me the element.However in the test script its unable to get the element.In google console when I try to get the element by `$('[data-model-cid="c279"]>label')` it is unable to fetch the element.So I think the :: before selector needs to be added in the selector to search the element. The Html is given below.How to write a selector with the :: before ?

```
    <div class="radio" data-model-cid="c279">
      :: before
    <input id="pac-item-care-plan-4 years-45924345-view261" class="js-care-plan-update" type="radio" value="45924345" name="pac-item-care-plan-view261" data-analytics-id="cpradio" data-groupid="472AB3B8BDAD4A4AA78A7CF484FFA7E4" data-offerid="F259143E766145DF8F50DF46F9EC10B7" data-action="add" checked="checked"/>
    <label class="no-wrap" for="pac-item-care-plan-4 years-45924345-view261">
      :: before
      4 years 
    <strong>(+ $39)</strong>
    </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: `:before` elements do not exist for javascript, as they are not actual elements. The `[data-model-cid="c279"] > label` should work, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: It is not working .In google console ```$('[data-model-cid="c279"]>label').text()``` gives  "" and ```$('[data-model-cid="c279"]>label')``` gives [] its unable to get the element

Comment: There could be many reasons for this - be it where you place your JS, whether you wait for `DOMContentLoaded`, ... But the query string is correct in regards to the code you posted and should select the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know you cannot do this, mainly because an `input` is an empty tag (self-closing) and it basically has no content.

within a `<div>` element if you look at the following example

```
<style>
    .my-div::before {
        content: 'before';
    }

    .my-div::after {
        content: 'after';
    }
</style>
<div class="my-div"></div>
```

You'll notice in the chrome devtools you'll get something like this

```
<div class="my-class">
    ::before
    ::after
</div>
```

This is possible because the `::before` and `::after` psuedo-elements live *inside* the div tag, if you add another child div with a height and a background you'll see the words *before* pop up above the child div and *after* pop up after the child div - this is because they are basically children but inserted in a *different* way (through CSS).

The following is what you're looking for the browser to do

```
<input type="radio"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="radio">
    ::before
    ::after
</input>
```

But this is wrong already since the input tag shouldn't have any content in it. Most browsers will probably ignore this or even try to *fix your markup for you* but you simply won't be able to get this working.

From the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore)

> "The :before and :after pseudo-elements elements interact with other
>   boxes... as if they were real elements inserted just inside their
>   associated element."

A correct `<input>` tag looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" />
```

And since this doesn't have any room to place the `::before` and `::after` in it won't work. You'll have to find an alternative solution unfortunately.